# django tastypie resource queryset filter doesn't work if resource is pulled into another

Tags: django, django-queryset, tastypie

Models

```
class Quote(models.model):
    quote_ref = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    order = models.Foreignkey('Order', related_name='quotes')
    version models.DecimalField(null=True, blank=True)
    requested_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    expiry_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    closed_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)

class Order(models.model):
    order_ref = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True)
    cost models.DecimalField(null=True, blank=True)
    order_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    delivery_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    .......
    .......
```

Resources

```
class RequestsResource(ModelResource):
    quotes = fields.ToManyField('api.resources.QuoteIndexResource', 'quotes', full=True, null=True)
    class Meta:
        queryset = Order.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'request'


class QuoteIndexResource(ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        queryset = Quote.objects.all().filter(closed_date__isnull=True)
        resource_name = 'index_quote'
```

If I use the `QuoteIndexResource` on its own the filter on the `queryset`works but if it is pulled into `RequestsResource` then the filter doesn't have any effect on the data.

Is there a way to make the `.filter(closed_date__isnull=True)` work in this scenario?

Comment: No takers anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bad I should have closed this question when I fixed it.
so I found if I used `attribute=lambda bundle` I would get errors.
but using just `lambda bundle:` It all works ok.

```
quotes = fields.ToManyField(
    'api.resources.QuoteIndexResource', lambda bundle: Quote.objects.filter(order=bundle.obj, closed_date__isnull=True),
    full=True, null=True
```

)

Answer (score 1):

It appears that `ToManyField`s in Tastypie are independent from their queryset setting in meta class.

The simple workaround is to use attribute with lambda expression:

```
quotes = fields.ToManyField(
    'api.resources.QuoteIndexResource',
    attribute=lambda bundle: Quote.objects.all().filter(
        order=bundle.obj, closed_date__isnull=True),
    full=True, null=True
)
```

Some more details in documentation: http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fields.html#tomanyfield